# Which one is the faster way to get the list of directories subprocess.Popen or os.listdir

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to retrieve the list of files in a directory. What would be the fastest way to do so 
using `subprocess.Popen` or using `os.listdir`. The directory contain 10000 of files. and this has to be done recursively to retrieve the list from the directory and its sub directories. I know we can use `os.walk` to retrieve the contents of directories but `os.walk` just not work for what I am suppose to do.

Thanks

Comment: I would expect `os.listdir` to be faster since you don't need to spawn a subprocess, and they probably use basically the same code to get the listing.  Why don't you `timeit` and see?

Comment: Why doesn't `os.walk` work for you?

Comment: @mgilson-I tested them both and found os.listdir to be faster but I dont know the reason behind it. thats why posted this question

Comment: @AnuragSharma: `os.walk` does more work but handles nested directories for you. If you can build a solution that traverses directories faster than `os.walk` using `os.listdir`, then by all means use `os.listdir`. But don't compare the two directly.

Answer (score 3):

`os.listdir` is very likely to be compiled c that calls the same base libc system methods that `ls` does.

In contrast, `subprocess.Popen` forks a whole new process which is an expensive system operation and requires new file handles to deal with tty operations.